# Setting refresh swiper handler in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I am using a `SwipeRefreshLayout` in one of my fragments that contains a ListView.

```
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);

    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {


        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            view.refreshDrawableState();
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

I do this to refresh my listView whenever I swipe, but nothing is getting updated.

My layout is implemented as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/match_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="255"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: I don't think `refreshDrawableState()` does what you think it does. You need to be updating your `Adapter`'s dataset there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the new list to the listview adapter.

```
private void refreshContent(){
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getNewTweets());
         mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
      });
}
```

Comment: Is this inside the `setOnRefreshListener` ?

Comment: yes you haven't updated the list that you received from the adapter